# I would like to transform a Jquery mousemove() Method and css() Method to pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mousemove

I am converting a Jquery script to Vanilla JS, I have difficulties to convert this piece of code:
where the region element are SVG illustration, and when the mouse move over, his position is captured ( with pageX and pageY) and inserted inside the html element (using style).

```js
  jQuery('region').on('mousemove', function (e) {
    description.css({
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY - 100,
         });

  });
```

I tried with something like that (a for loop), but it's not working:

```js
  let description2 = document.querySelectorAll('description');

  for ( let i = 0; i < description2.length; i++ ) {
  
    description2[i].setAttribute("style", "left:" + e.pageX + ' top:' + (e.pageY - 100) );

  }
```

So, what is a good method to convert this Jquery snippet to pure Vanilla JS ?
I guess that Jquery('region') would be convert to:

`document.getElementsByClassName('my-element-name');`

A solution to convert this snippet will help me a lot to understand better the Jquery to Javascript conversion.

Comment: You'll need to `addEventListener` for the mousemove. I would recommend creating your styles in CSS and then adding/removing the class as necessary.

Comment: Thanks! Using addEventListener help to transform the jquery on('mousemove'.... to javascript event handler: document.querySelector('test').
    addEventListener('mousemove', myFunction);